# Is there a way to determine whether a directive scope "&" item has been set to something?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following note that `bar` does not have a value.

Instance:

```
<my-directive
    foo="foo"
    bar="" /></my-directive>
```

Directive:

```
return function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            foo: '&',
            bar: '&',
        },
        template: template,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: controller,
    };
};
```

How can I tell in the controller that `scope.bar` has not been set to anything?

I am using Angular 1.4.

Comment: if not bound to anything i believe it will be null. If you do a null check on that variable you can see if it has value or not. If not it means it isn't bound to something. Is that what you asked for?

Comment: It is wrapped in a function I believe.

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute value itself can be checked with

```
$attrs.bar == true;
```

As it was mentioned, `&` bindings result in wrapper function that is always truthy.

Comment: Cool didn't know that